Chinese scroll writing seal marks (Characters identified: 劉建余書 / 劉建余印)
Tôi muốn biết liệu có ai có thể dịch được dấu ấn đỏ và dòng chữ trên những cuộn giấy cổ này không.
enter image description here

Lưu Kiến Dư thư / Lưu Kiến Dư ấn

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

thank you very much
